# Google not using _escaped_fragment_ for homepage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-search

I have javascript (angular) based website. As well I have proxy pages for each page that are visible for google crawlers via _escaped_fragment_ parameter. All redirectis works fine. I don't know why but Google uses home page without proxy (the rest of pages works fine). Thas why I see some bad text during google search.

[image]

Is anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You need this meta tag:

```html
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```

For more information: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started